# Calculate integral of$\sqrt{r^2 (1+\cos^2\big(\frac{t}{2}\big)}$

Tags: integration

I need to calculate the length of Viviani curve, given with it parametrization $$c(t)=\big(r(1+\cos {t}),r\sin {t},2 r\sin{\frac{t}{2}}\big)$$
I started by calculating integral of $$\sqrt{r^2 (1+\cos^2\big(\frac{t}{2}\big)}$$
It would make it easier if someone could just calculate this integral step by step. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your parametrization a bit off?-http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VivianisCurve.html

Comment: I need to calculate exactly that one, and the length of it.

Comment: it's also an elliptic integral so unless you want to approximate it...

Comment: Please correct the Latex, $r$ should appear in front, length dimension does not tally.

Answer (score 0):

$ (x,y,z) $ are given as parameters of $t$.  $L = \int \sqrt{   \dot x^2 + \dot y^2 + \dot z^2} dt. $

Comment: I did that and got $$\sqrt{r^2 (1+\cos^2\big(\frac{t}{2}\big)}$$

Comment: Not correct, show some steps.

Comment: sqrt(r^2sin^(t)+r^2cos^2(t)+r^2cos^2(t/2))= sqrt(r^2(sin^2(t)+cos^2(t))+r^2coc^2(t/2))=sqrt(r^2+r^2cos^2(t/2))